# In cricket, is it a no-ball even if the ball hits the wicket?

Tags: rules, cricket

I play cricket every summer and have been ever since I was little. During a match I was bowling. The rule in the league I play for is

> If the ball is bowled (without hitting the ground) above waist height, it is a no ball.

Now surely, if a ball is bowled above waist height, it will not hit the wicket.

My question is, if the ball is bowled above waist height, but ends up hitting the wicket - is that out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. See [Law 24.16](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball/):

> When No ball has been called, neither batsman shall be out under any of the Laws except 33 (Handled the ball), 34 (Hit the ball twice), 37 (Obstructing the field) or 38 (Run out).

At least under the standard Laws of Cricket (specifically, [Law 42.6 and 42.7](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-42-fair-and-unfair-play/)), it's a No ball as soon as it passes the batsmen, so it doesn't matter that it hit the wicket - it's still a No ball and therefore the batsman cannot be out bowled.

Comment: Its worth noting however that it is above waist height of the batsmen stood upright at the popping crease, and so could pass him above waist height if he batting out of crease or down the wicket.  Also the waist is around the naval not neccessarily the waist of the trousers.

Answer (score -3):

It is a wicket no matter how high the ball goes, if it hits the stumps

Comment: Are you able to provide some references to support this answer?

Answer (score -4):

Considering the two possibilities :
If the batsman is standing well inside the crease.Then there is no way possible for the ball to have passed the batsman above waist height and suddenly defy the laws of physics and trajectory, and decrease height mid air in such a short distance and hit the stumps.(Well, even if the ball does go on to hit the stumps by some sort of magic or an extra terrestrial intervention, it is out ).

2.If the batsman is standing outside the crease.
Now it is possible for the ball to go on to hit the stumps even if  the ball had passed the batsman above waist height.
In this case the result is OUT even though the ball was above waist height when it passed the batsman, because it is considered to be the batsman's fault/choice that he was outside the crease (otherwise it wouldn't have been above his waist had he been inside the crease, or would not have hit the stumps at all as i explained above in the first scenario)
The umpire made a mistake??????

Comment: Could you make it clear which Law of cricket you are basing your part 2 on?